# Apache Nifi: Using HandleHTTPRequest and GetFile in the same flow

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to build a new Data Ingestion flow using Apache Nifi.

I am trying to use the HandleHTTPRequest and GetFile in the same flow but Nifi is not allowing it.

We will be receiving a JSON file using Rest API call from a User Interface.  I have used HandleHttpRequest processor for receiving this request.

We also have to read a configuration JSON file and then proceed with the processing. I am trying to use GetFile here, but unable to connect the two.

Can you please let me know how this can be achieved or am I doing anything wrong here.  Thanks for your support!

Comment: HandleHTTPRequest  -> ExtractJsonPath without saving the file to local.

Comment: Thanks Lamanus for your quick response.  But these are two different json. One from the User Interface containing user inputs, the other one is a configuration json stored in local path with other database connectivity details stored in it.

Answer (score 4):

GetFile is a source processor and does not allow an incoming connection since it is the starting point of a flow.

You can have HandleHttpRequest -> FetchFile.

Comment: Thank you Bryan, FetchFile processor worked for me.  I am new to Nifi and did not know GetFile is a source processor.  Thanks again and appreciate your support!

Comment: @KavipriyaM glad you got it working, please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

I used FetchFile instead of GetFile and was able to connect it to the HandleHttpRequest processor.